# Use @_components

Tags: node.js, next.js

I have a NextJS 13 app with this structure:

```
app
   _components
      header.tsx
      footer.tsx
      login.tsx
   (routes)
      about
         page.tsx
      blog
         page.tsx
      contact
         page.tsx
```

In my tsconfig.json I have:

```
"paths": {
      "@_*": ["../*"]
    }
```

The idea is that for example in the `contact page` I use:

```
import Login from '@components/Login'
```

This does not work.

Also within the `_components` directory, it does not work. For example, if I want to import "Login" in "Header" like so:

```
import Login from '@components/Login'
```

I get the message that the module cannot be found. I understand that within `_components` I am in the current dir and that I need to use `./` and ('../' is for the parent dir).

Challenge is how to write the `path` correctly for both my scenarios (_components in current dir and _components in parent dir)?

Comment: added `"baseUrl": "."` in my tsconfig.json but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `tsconfig.json` is on the same level as the `app` folder.

Try the following:

```
// tsconfig.json
"paths": {
   "@/*": ["./app/*"]
}
```

Then update your imports like so:

```
import Login from '@/_components/login'
```

Comment: I actually solved it already like this...`"@*": ["./app/_*"]` and the import then with @components. Looks neater, but your answer I accept anyways.